# Plotting in matlab / octave by grouping numbers into a range

Tags: matlab, plot, gnuplot, octave

I'm trying to have the **data be the x-axis** and the **y-axis be the amount of values grouped by 10**.  See Plot below as example

I tried using **bar(x)** but I'm not sure how you get the numbers in the correct categories for plotting.

example:
if the data is `x=1,5.3,9,10.5,12,13,15.2,25,191,192.4`

```
the group 0-10 should be 1,5.3,9
the group 10.1-20 should be 10.5,12,13,15.2
the group of 20.1-30 should be 25
.
.
.
the group of 190.1-200 should be 191,192.4
```

[image: Barplot]

PS:  **I'm using octave 3.8.1 which is like matlab**

Comment: Are you looking for a histogram? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html

Comment: @Daniel thanks I just couldn't remember the name of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`histc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html). But `histc` considers equality at the left edge of each bin, not at its right edge:

> `bincounts = histc(x,binranges)` counts the number of values in `x` that are within each specified bin range. The input, `binranges`, determines the endpoints for each bin. The output, `bincounts`, contains the number of elements from `x` in each bin.
>
> For example, if `binranges` equals the vector `[0,5,10,13]`, then `histc` creates four bins. The first bin includes values greater than or equal to `0` and strictly less than `5`. The second bin includes values greater than or equal to `5` and less than `10`, and so on. The last bin contains the scalar value `13`.

To set the equality condition at the left edges, it's better to do it manually with `bsxfun`:

```
y = diff(sum(bsxfun(@le, x(:), 0:10:200), 1));
```

`sum(bsxfun(...), 1)` finds how many entries of `x` are smaller or equal to `0`, `10`, ... `200`; and then `diff(...)` gives the desired result `y`:

```
y =
     3     4     1     0     0     0     0     [...]     2
```

You can then use `bar(y)` to plot the bars. If you additionally want to change the texts shown on the x-axis, set the `'xticklabel'` property of the axes:

```
bar(y);
strings = {'0-10', '10-20', '20-30'}; %// manually define all strings up to '190-200'
set(gca, 'xticklabel', strings)
```

Comment: that looks really nice but the x axis goes from 1...20 instead of the data values.  Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1):

With your data, you can use:

```
x = [1 5.3 9 10.5 12 13 15.2 25 191 192.4];
nbins = round(max(x)/10+.5);
hist(x, nbins);
```

This is the result:
[image: This is the result]

Comment: This seems to work and is quite simple, but is it assured that `hist` considers equality at the _right_ edge of each bin? I couldn't find that in the documentation

Comment: `hist` by default, use only ten bars. You can change the number of bars with a parameter. You can write it directly, e.g., `hist(x, 20)`, or compute this number using your maximum array value.

Comment: Of course; but that doesn't answer my question. In the example, how do you know if the first interval is `(0 10]` or `[0 10)`?

Comment: By hypothesis. :-) More seriously: instead of `nbins = round(max(x)/10+.5);` you can simply write `nbins = round((max(x)-min(x))/10+.5);`.